# How to make Local branches configured for 'git pull':

Tags: git

I am trying to create a branch named springdevelopment and push the code it to the git.

```
git checkout -b springdevelopment 
git add .

git commit -m 'initial commit'
git push origin springdevelopment 
git checkout --track origin/springdevelopment
```

when i executed  git remote show origin . I am missing "spring development" in local branches git pull section.

Can you please explain what is happened and what is the wrong i have done.

Thanks for your valuable information in advance.

Comment: why do we get " The connection was aborted" exception....
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: as adam's answer suggested, what you missed is the -u flag with git push command. -u sets upstream. alternatively you could explicitly do `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/springdevelopment springdevelopment`. This way local branch is said to be 'tracking' the remote branch, so that you can do `git pull` to merge later

Answer (score 13):

```
git checkout -b springdevelopment 
git add .

git commit -m 'initial commit'
git push -u origin springdevelopment
```

no need to do this:

```
git checkout --track origin/springdevelopment
```

You can always update tracking later with:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/springdevelopment
```

update your refspec to:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:user/project.git
    fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Thanks Adam for your quick reply.I want to make my springdevelopment branch to be visible in the git pull section also. When i am executing  git remote show origin the result is missing springdevelopment branch for gitpull

Comment: then maybe what you want to do is update the refspec: `git fetch refs/heads/* refs/remotes/origin/*` and to see what you want you can do `git branch -a` (after setting the tracking as Adam suggested)

Answer (score 2):

My `git pull` wasn't pulling from the correct remote. I realized I added a second upstream `github` and that overtook my "master" branch.

So I modified my `.git/config` file from:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = github
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

to:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 0):

While I think there is an option to make push update the tracking refs (`refs/remote/...`), I just can't see any trace of it in the documentation right now. Just call

```
git fetch
```

after pushing to update them.